# Como hacer transparente la seleccion de un boton en html

Tags: html, css, web

necesito ayuda, para ocultar la seccion de un boton en html, esto solo sucede cuando visualizo la pagina en vercion movil, ya que, en vercion escritorio si puedo ocultar el recuadro de seleccion, aqui les dejo una imagen para que se guien:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buenas @Electro, para poder ayudarte mejor deberías añadir el código concreto que no te funciona. Te recomiendo leer  [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Para ello, debes aplicar el estilo **:active** al botón.

```
button:active{ background-color: transparent;}
```

Si no te funciona con eso (no veo tu código como para poder valorarlo) tienes otra opción:

Añade **ontouchstart=""** a tu etiqueta body:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
```

Aquí puedes encontrar más información: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

https://www.beacontechnologies.com/blog/2015/05/simple-little-tricks-for-web-transition-touch-events-on-mobile-devices/